# Random adding to set

Tags: python, set

So I'm working on some words and I wanted to add words longer than 1 to set and for some reason adding is random. I have these strings in list and then I'm adding if longer than 1 to set and then I display to see how does it look and the result is always diffrent and not even close to order in list? Why is this happening?

```
for s in new_string:
    print(s)
```

Result (always the same):

```
this
etext
was
produced
by
normal
```

And then I'm adding to set and try to display:

```
ana = set()
for s in new_string:
    if(len(s) > 1):
        ana.add(s)

for s in ana:
    print(s)
```

Result (it prints random values instead of starting from beginning):

```
referred
account
undertook
situation
conquest
brestlitovsk
```

Comment: `set`s are *unordered* objects.

Comment: just convert to a list (and make sure it's in the order you want) before you print it.

Comment: There is an [`orderedset` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/orderedset) on pypi you could use instead of Python's built-in `set` type.